# VisualEditor problem-404 error-curl7 error

Tags: php, node.js, mediawiki, parsoid, mediawiki-visualeditor

my wiki :

```
Product Version
MediaWiki   1.32.0
PHP 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.5 (apache2handler)
MySQL   5.7.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
ICU 55.1
Lua 5.1.5
link: wikijoo.ir
```

my config.yaml seup:

```
worker_heartbeat_timeout: 300000

logging:

    level: info

#metrics:

#    type: log

services:

  - module: src/lib/index.js

    entrypoint: apiServiceWorker

    conf:

        # For backwards compatibility, and to continue to support non-static

        # configs for the time being, optionally provide a path to a

        # localsettings.js file.  See localsettings.example.js

        #localsettings: ./localsettings.js

        # Set your own user-agent string

        # Otherwise, defaults to:

        #   'Parsoid/<current-version-defined-in-package.json>'

        #userAgent: 'My-User-Agent-String'

        # Configure Parsoid to point to your MediaWiki instances.

        mwApis:

        - # This is the only required parameter,

          # the URL of you MediaWiki API endpoint.

          uri: 'http://wikijoo.ir/api.php/'

          # The "domain" is used for communication with Visual Editor

          # and RESTBase.  It defaults to the hostname portion of

          # the `uri` property above, but you can manually set it

          # to an arbitrary string. It must match the "domain" set

          # in $wgVirtualRestConfig.

          domain: 'wikijoo.ir'  # optional

          # To specify a proxy (or proxy headers) specific to this prefix
```

and my localsetting.php :

```
$wgVirtualRestConfig['modules']['parsoid'] = [

// URL to the Parsoid instance - use port 8142 if you use the Debian package - the parameter 'URL' was first used but is now deprecated (string)

'url' => 'http://wikijoo.ir',

// Parsoid "domain" (string, optional) - MediaWiki >= 1.26

'domain' => 'wikijoo.ir',

// Parsoid "prefix" (string, optional) - deprecated since MediaWiki 1.26, use 'domain'

'prefix' => 'wikijoo.ir',

// Forward cookies in the case of private wikis (string or false, optional)

'forwardCookies' => true,

// request timeout in seconds (integer or null, optional)

'timeout' => null,

// Parsoid HTTP proxy (string or null, optional)

'HTTPProxy' => null,

// whether to parse URL as if they were meant for RESTBase (boolean or null, optional)

'restbaseCompat' => null,

];
```

and parsoid is active

sudo systemctl status parsoid:

```
● parsoid.service - LSB: Web service converting HTML+RDFa to MediaWiki wikitext and back

   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/parsoid; bad; vendor preset: enabled)

   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-08-05 10:44:26 UTC; 1 day 20h ago

     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

  Process: 3861 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/parsoid stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

  Process: 3875 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/parsoid start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

   CGroup: /system.slice/parsoid.service

           ├─3884 /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/lib/parsoid/src/bin/server.js -c /etc/mediawiki/parsoid/config.yaml >> /var/log/parsoid/parsoid.log 2>&1

           └─3887 /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/lib/parsoid/src/bin/server.js -c /etc/mediawiki/parsoid/config.yaml

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

When I want to edit an article, I get the message below:

Error loading data from server: apierror-visualeditor-docserver-http: HTTP 404. Would you like to try again?

please help me

best regards